# Does anyone have real world example for random point pattern

Tags: spatial, point-process

I have been writing a paper and need to give examples for the different patterns that are result of point process. It has to be real world examples. For clustered I give the example of settlements and train stations, with the logic of real estate developers want their estates to be close to local amenities and shop owners want to be next to public transport so it is all clustered. This is in the suburbans I forgot to mention. For dispersed I give the example of gas stations which usually try not to be very close to each other with the logic of drivers not really researching where is the next texaco (if that is what their station of choice) and when they understand they need gas they'll just stop at the first one.

I still can't find a good example for random point pattern in the real world. I watch CSI and they say that crime is random but from two sample data that they gave us it is clustered. And it also makes sense that it's not random because burglars like high class neighborhoods.

Can anyone help with an example for real world random point pattern?

Comment: Navid - Don't know if you are still interested in this question but you might want to clearly define "real world" in light of the way real estate data is collected and disseminated. I have nearly 50 years in the field, the last half in academia, with very spotty results in this area. Look at the most recent post at www.mathestate.com for details. My best. RJB

Comment: Bird nesting paterns:  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304380005005673    also see the book "Spatial Statistics" by Brian Ripley for examples.